# Passing an array as a function argument in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, arguments

If I have this function:

```
void initPoints(sf::Vector2f points[]);
```

Why can I do this:

```
sf::Vector2f[] vecs = {sf::Vector2f(0,0), etc};
initPoints(vecs);
```

But can't do this?

```
initPoints({sf::Vector2f(0,0), etc});
```

VS gives me an error on the second one, but not on the first one.

Comment: Because function parameter `sf::Vector2f  points[]` really means `sf::Vector2f* points`. It is a syntactic strangeness of the language.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  I'm not trying to be difficult:  the code you want to use is wrong for a slighlty different reason in C++11 than it was in earlier versions of the language, but it's possible to add an overload to fix that code in C++11.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it still displays the same error; If I create the array outside of the function call, it works, but if I try creating it in the inside of the function call it does not...

Comment: @MaxLybbert I think I'm using C++11.

Comment: I find it odd that `initPoints` doesn't take a length.  I mean, aside from the fact that Stepanov convinced everybody to take begin/end pairs instead of pointers and length parameters.

Comment: After all, whats the error the compiler give you??

Comment: @MaxLybbert I think I might not understand you. As I said, I'm trying to learn C++ and come from Java. Can't you just call thearray.length or something like that too? Or why would you need an extra variable?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda It says that my arguments are not those of the function definition.

Comment: @Fly is `Vector2F` a class created by you. If so, could you post the code?

Comment: @RaydelMiranda It is a class by the game library "SFML". (I actually forgot to put the sf:: in the example, going to do that right now.) I actually don't think the class is the problem, since I tried it with int arrays/vectors too, and it gave exactly the same result.

Comment: @Fly have just tried and no errors, the code I tried is: `void init(vector<int> v){}; init({1,2,3,4,5});` are you sure you're using C++11? What compiler are you using? What version of VS or GCC, etc..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65096/discussion-between-raydel-miranda-and-fly).

Comment: @RaydelMiranda That is because you re trying different code. The class `sf::Vector2f` is irrelevant to this problem. The same would happen with `int`.

Comment: @Fly `{a, b, c}` is not an array. It is a special kind of initializer that can be used to initialize arrays. But it cannot be used to initialize a pointer. As I said in my first comment, your function's parameter is a pointer.

Comment: @RaydelMiranda That's weird, I tried exactly the same thing too... I'm going to restart VS and try again. /Edit/ WOW, it actually works now, thank you very much!! I have no idea why it did not work on the first try...

Comment: @juanchopanza But if a pointer is basically the same as an array in the function definition, what happens with something like int * something? Will it get interpreted as a pointer to a single integer or as a pointer to a list of integers? And theoretically, couldn't I declare something like {1, 2, 3}& to match the int * something? Since the & symbol gives the address. By the way, thank you guys so much for your help!

Comment: `int*` is a pointer to an `int`. That's all. The thing it, C++ gets pointer arithmetic from C, so you can use a pointer to an int to access ints next to it, which means you can almost treat a pointer to int as an array of int. This is so confusing and dangerous that you'll quickly learn to avoid it and use types with better defined semantics.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks! I think I might have understood this a little bit, and I guess for now I'll only use classes like vector. Problem solved, I guess!

Comment: @Fly *don't* update your question or title with "Solved". Marking an answer as correct will effectively do that for you.

Comment: @crashmstr Whoops, did not know that. Thanks for telling me. Editing it now.

Comment: @Fly "Can't you just call thearray.length or something like that too? Or why would you need an extra variable?" No, you cannot. Arrays in C++ are very lightweight and are essentially pointers to chunks of memory. They have no "recollection" of their size. Take a look at [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/size/) if you desire that kind of functionality.

Comment: @AtlasC1 That is wrong and misleading. Arrays in C++ are not pointers, and their type *does* hold the size. You can always get the size of an array, if you have an array.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think you misunderstood. I did not say arrays in C++ are pointers; I said they are "essentially" pointers. Sure, you can calculate the number of elements in an array using sizeof, but that is minimally useful, especially in the context of OP's question, considering arrays decay to pointers when passed as function parameters (unless they are passed by reference).

Comment: @AtlasC1 I think the misunderstanding is yours. Arrays don't decay to pointers when passed as function parameters. They decay to a pointer to their first element when used to initialize or assign to a pointer. They are not copyable or assignable, which is one reason there isn't a syntax that allows you to pass them to a function by value. But you can pass them by reference, or pass pointers to them. In both cases the size information is kept.

Comment: @juanchopanza We aren't on the same page - let's continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65164/c-arrays).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `std::vector` or `std::array` you can resolve your problem easier :)
Furthermore, `std::vector` is RAII-conform, so you don't have to manage the memory by yourself. Generally, STL classes are better than C-type arrays.

```
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>
// ...
std::vector<sf::Vector2f> vecs = { Vector2f(0,0), etc };
```

Then:

```
initPoints(const std::vector<sf::Vector2f>& vec) {
    // ...
}
initPoints(vecs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually already tried with std::vectors, but what I need is to be able to init an array/vector in a single line, since my "real" problem is that I have a class extending a superclass, and I'm calling the superclasses constructor - The constructor of my superclass needs an array/vector/whatever, and I can't create a variable for this vector/array first, so I need to basically do it in one line. I asked my question the way I did because I find it actually interesting in general why this isnt possible and how to solve it.

Comment: Something like this:
BaseClass::BaseClass() : SuperClass(std::vector<sf::Vector2f> { Vector2f(0,0), etc }) {}
? (using <initializer_list>)

Answer (score 1):

C++ generally doesn't allow you to pass an actual array as a function parameter.  It has a convenience feature that makes you think that's possible, in that you can actually pass a pointer.

In other words:

```
void initPoints(sf::Vector2f points[]);
```

Is the same thing as

```
void initPoints(sf::Vector2f* points);
```

Note that `initPoints` doesn't know the length of `points`, so generally you also pass a length parameter:

```
void initPoints(sf:Vector2f* points, size_t length);
```

What you're trying to do simply isn't valid pre-C++11.  In C++11 you can overload `initPoints()` to take a `std::initializer_list<sf::Vector2f>`, and the syntax will work fine.

---

The kind of array you're using is often called a "C-style array."  It exists in C, and has existed in C++ from the beginning.  It has various limitations, such as what you've just run into.  It looks like you really want a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).  There is some nuance to using `std::vector`s, and I don't know your level of C++ understanding, so I don't know if the phrases "usually you don't want to pass them by value" or "I would recommend you imitate STL functions and pass begin/end iterators instead" mean anything to you.  You will eventually come across the parts of the language that make those statements useful.  You don't need to worry about them right now.

Comment: There's no exception. `void initPoints(sf::Vector2f[3] points);` is syntactically invalid. And `void initPoints(sf::Vector2f points[3]);` is the same as ``void initPoints(sf::Vector2f* points);`